# What method in JButton actually calls its ActionListener?

Tags: java, events, actionlistener

So I know how to program a GUI to get a JButton to react to a mouse press:  Implement an ActionListener, and add that to the button...

What I want to know is what method in JButton (or something it inherits from ) take care of passing the mouse press event to the actionPeformed() method which is waiting for it.  I don't need the details of how it works...but I would like to know what methods are involved.

I have tried to find it in the JavaDoc, but there is such a long inheritance chain, when you don't know where to look, you could be looking forever.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You could throw a ``RuntimeException`` such as a ``NullPointerException`` in your actionlistener, then take a look at the stacktrace. Or you could put a breakpoint in your actionlistener and take a look at the callstack.

Comment: Excellent...this worked thanks.  I think my answer is fireActionPerformed in AbstractButton